# Putting All Top Categories as Optgroup from Category Table in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, nested

I am half stuck in putting all my top categories into Optgroup, tried several ways, took lot of references from stackoverflow, but failed to achieve as I am required.

Took reference from [here](http://www.thesoftwareguy.in/create-category-tree-php-mysql) and built my nested categories:

```
function fetchCategoryTree($parent = 0, $spacing = '', $user_tree_array = '') {
    global $conn;

    if (!is_array($user_tree_array)) {
        $user_tree_array = array();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `parent_id` FROM `acct_categs` WHERE `parent_id` = '".$parent."' ORDER BY `name` ASC";
    $query = $conn->Execute($sql);

    if (count($query) > 0) {
        $current_parent = '';
        while ($row = $query->FetchRow()) {
            $user_tree_array[] = array("catid" => $row['id'], "catname" => $spacing . $row['name']);
            $user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTree($row['id'], $spacing . '-&nbsp;', $user_tree_array);
        }
    }
    return $user_tree_array;
}

function categoryoption(){
    $categoryList = fetchCategoryTree();
    $dropdown = '<select name="category_id">';
    foreach($categoryList as $cl) {
        $dropdown .= "\n<option value=\"".$cl["catid"]."\">".$cl["catname"]."</option>";
    }

    $dropdown .= "</select>";
    return $dropdown;
}

echo categoryoption();
```

So when I echo this I get the following dropdown:

```
<select name="category_id">
<option value="91">Assets</option>
<option value="3">-&nbsp;Capital Assets</option>
<option value="23">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Accum. Amort. -Furn. &amp; Equip.</option>
<option value="25">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Accum. Amort. -Vehicle</option>
<option value="22">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Office Furniture &amp; Equipment</option>
<option value="24">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Vehicle</option>
<option value="1">-&nbsp;Current Assets</option>
<option value="15">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Accounts Receivables</option>
<option value="16">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Allowance for doubtful accounts</option>
<option value="13">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Checking Account</option>
....</select>
```

What I want is like this, https://jsfiddle.net/sbnzp1wL/

```
<select name="category_id">
<optgroup label="Assets"></optgroup>
<optgroup label="Capital Assets"></optgroup>
<option value="23">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Accum. Amort. -Furn. &amp; Equip.</option>
<option value="25">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Accum. Amort. -Vehicle</option>
<option value="22">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Office Furniture &amp; Equipment</option>
<option value="24">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Vehicle</option>
<optgroup label="Current Assets"></optgroup>
<option value="15">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Accounts Receivables</option>
<option value="16">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Allowance for doubtful accounts</option>
<option value="13">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Checking Account</option>
<option value="14">-&nbsp;-&nbsp;Petty Cash</option>
....</select>
```

I read it's not possible in nested queries within stackoverflow, but I also learnt it's possible from [here](http://www.robertmullaney.com/2009/09/17/phpmysql-nested-select-using-optgroup-with-left-join-on-same-table-in-a-single-query/).

But with that link help, my top categories listed 2nd level categories and 2nd level listed it's children. Somehow, from that also I did not achieve what I wanted as.

My table values are [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0387f/1)

---

Finally got it working as per my need, if someone needs it, am posting it here... All big thanks to @stj (answer accepted and upvoted)

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `parent_id` FROM `acct_categs` ORDER BY `name` ASC";
$query = $conn->Execute($sql);
// build a lookup array with all elements
$all = array();
$hasChildren = array();
while ($row = $query->FetchRow()) {
    $all[$row["id"]] = $row;
    $hasChildren[$row["parent_id"]] = true;
}

// recursive processing function
function process($rows, $hasChildren, $parentId, $level = 0) {
    foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {

        if ($row["parent_id"] === $parentId) {
            // this is the element we are looking for
            $pad = str_repeat("  ", $level);

            if (isset($hasChildren[$id])) {
                // the element has children
                $line = "\n<optgroup label=\"{$row["name"]}\"></optgroup>";
                //$line = $pad . $row["id"] . " - " . $row["name"] . " (has children)";
            } else {
                // the element does not have any children
                $line = "\n<option value=\"{$row["id"]}\">{$row["name"]}</option>";
                //$line = $pad . $row["id"] . " - " . $row["name"] . " (no children)";
            }
            // print it
            print $line . "\n";
            // finally process the children

            if (isset($hasChildren[$id])) {
                process($rows, $hasChildren, $id, $level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<select name="category_id">';
// start processing    
$print = process($all, $hasChildren, "0");
echo $print;
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is a depth-first recursion that renders your nested data.

I suggest querying all values from the database with a single query and process them in PHP. This saves you from issuing lots of individual database queries (one per element).

Once you've queried all relevant rows, you can walk them in PHP recursively.
Here is some code that will do that.

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `parent_id` FROM `acct_categs` ORDER BY `name` ASC";
$query = $conn->Execute($sql);

// build a lookup array with all elements
$all = array();
$hasChildren = array();

while ($row = $query->FetchRow()) {
  $all[$row["id"]] = $row;
  $hasChildren[$row["parent_id"]] = true;
}

// recursive processing function
function process($rows, $hasChildren, $parentId, $level = 0) {
  foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
    if ($row["parent_id"] === $parentId) {
      // this is the element we are looking for
      $pad = str_repeat("  ", $level);
      if (isset($hasChildren[$id])) {
        // the element has children
        $line = $pad . $row["id"] . " - " . $row["name"] . " (has children)";
      }
      else {
         // the element does not have any children
        $line = $pad . $row["id"] . " - " . $row["name"] . " (no children)";
      }

      // print it
      print $line . "\n";

      // finally process the children
      if (isset($hasChildren[$id])) {
        process($rows, $hasChildren, $id, $level + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}

// start processing    
process($all, $hasChildren, 0);
```

Note that it won't print nested optgroups. The reason is that I am not sure where the optgroups should go. I think optgroup elements shouldn't be nested. But if you really want to do that, go ahead.

Additionally, you may want to adjust the parts of the code that populates `$line` to your needs.

Comment: I had to add double quote to `process($all, $hasChildren, "0")` to echo and it printed this `91 - Assets (has children) 94 - Costs (has children) 93 - Income (has children) 92 - Liabilities (has children) `, as per my need there is also one more level which needs to be printed.

Comment: Well, your database's `Execute` and `FetchRow` methods are called in the example code but I have no idea what they do because of their code not being shown. They seem to return at least the `parent_id` values as strings and not numeric values, which is kind of unexpected. My example code assumes that the `parent_id` values are numeric as shown in the table definition. If your `parent_id` values are actually strings or are stored in PHP as strings, then you will need to adjust the line `if ($row["parent_id"] === $parentId) {`. In this line, change the `===` to a `==`.

Comment: Yes, it did work great, thank you so much, it nearly took me 4 big days for me to get what I want, you really cracked it. Thanks again. I have edited my question with final solution. +1 for your help and accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Get all cats with `parent_id = 0`, than loop it, and get childs. Parent category wrapp in `<optgroup></optgroup>`, child in `<option></option>`.

Comment: I got all cats from `parent_id = '0'` only

Comment: Interesting code here:

`$user_tree_array[] = array("catid" => $row['id'], "catname" => $spacing . $row['name']);
            $user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTree($row['id'], $spacing . '-&nbsp;', $user_tree_array);`

Comment: Could you please point me with the coding what exactly should I do?

Comment: In code above you have overwrite array `$user_tree_array[]` with another function response, so   `$user_tree_array[]` doesn't has any sense.

Comment: Try  `$user_tree_array[$row['id']] = fetchCategoryTree($row['id'], $spacing . '-&nbsp;', $user_tree_array);`

Comment: No, it does not list child categories at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75552/discussion-between-mcklayin-and-sammry).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a parent ID check to your `$categoryList` loop:

```
function fetchCategoryTree($parent = 0, $spacing = '', $user_tree_array = '') {
    global $conn;

    if (!is_array($user_tree_array)) {
        $user_tree_array = array();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `parent_id` FROM `acct_categs` WHERE `parent_id` = '".$parent."' ORDER BY `name` ASC";
    $query = $conn->Execute($sql);

    if (count($query) > 0) {
        $current_parent = '';
        while ($row = $query->FetchRow()) {
            $user_tree_array[] = array("catid" => $row['id'], "catname" => $spacing . $row['name'], "parentid" => $row['parent_id']);
            $user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTree($row['id'], $spacing . '-&nbsp;', $user_tree_array);
        }
    }
    return $user_tree_array;
}

function categoryoption(){
    $categoryList = fetchCategoryTree();
    $dropdown = '<select name="category_id">';
    foreach($categoryList as $cl) {
        if ($c1["parentid"] == '0') {
            $dropdown .= "\n<optgroup label=\"".$cl["catname"]."\"></optgroup>";
        } else {
            $dropdown .= "\n<option value=\"".$cl["catid"]."\">".$cl["catname"]."</option>";
        }
    }

    $dropdown .= "</select>";
    return $dropdown;
}

echo categoryoption();
```

Comment: nope, optgroup is being added to all fetched categories. Edited: Sorry, I had to add `$c1["parent_id"] == "0")` `double quote for 0`, it worked for 1st level category, but second level category also optgroup needed.

Comment: Hi @sammry, I've updated my answer code by adding `parentid` to the `$c1` array so it's available for comparison -- let me know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "second level category also optgroup needed"? [`<optgroup>` elements cannot be nested within one another](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup).

Comment: Hi, I had added the `parentid` for the first time. My issue is there is a 2nd level category `<optgroup label="Capital Assets"></optgroup>` which also needs to be optgrouped, but yes, for 1st level category, your suggestion worked. Now, I need it for 2nd level categories. Thanks.

Comment: May I have your *skype* account ?

Answer (score 0):

I like querying all values at once and ordering them with coalesce. It's the simplest option I've used.

```
<label>Category<br>
    <select name="category_id">
        <option value="0"> -- Choose Category -- </option>
<? 
        //All Categories
        $sql = "SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM acct_categs ORDER BY COALESCE((SELECT NULLIF(parent_id,0)), id), NULLIF(parent_id,0)";
        $catQuery = $conn->Execute($sql);
        if($catQuery->num_rows > 0) { 
            while($cat = $catQuery->fetch_object()){ 

                if($cat->parentId == 0){

                    echo '<optgroup label="'.$cat->title.'"></optgoup>';

                } else { 

                    echo '<option value="'.$cat->id.'">'.$cat->title.'</option>'; 

                }
            }
        }    
?>
    </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Optgroup should not open and close in a line. Other options should come inside optgroup. But your query is great.